# "I don't know what the story is about, except that it's about a basketball team." Do you reply to first or second clause; me neither / me too?

Tags: grammaticality, agreement

I am a native speaker, but I know that natives often use incorrect grammar.

- "I don't know what the story is about, except that it's about a basketball team."

Do you reply to first or second clause: me neither / me too?

It feels natural to me to respond to the second clause, so I would say "me too" in agreement with the grammatically positive second clause. i.e. The last thing I heard.

A nonnative speaker asked me about this, thinking grammatically you would respond to the first clause, and say "me neither". I actually assume they are right since it is the independent clause (I think? I am not so great at grammar) but wanted to double check with the experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clause “that it’s about a basketball team” is acting here as a noun phrase: it’s an object of the verb *know*. So your sentence is essentially the same as

> I don’t know anyone here except Sue.

So you are right—if someone else wished to report that their state of knowledge about the story was the same as yours, the way to do it would indeed be, “Me neither.”